# How to load multiple images from FirebaseStorage in flutter when permissions is needed?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, firebase-security

What I'm trying to do is to show list of items as Card widget each. So each Card will contains an Image, title, text, button..
similar to this:

[image]

steps are:

1- Load products-data from **Firebase-Store** using **StreamBuilder**(Done).

2- Thumbnail URL of the products loads from database then loads image from **Firebase-Storage** using **NetworkImage** (Done).

3- I believe this is a wrong way to load the images, because this will not work after changing the security rules of the **Firebase-Storage** which is expected.

My new FirebaseStorage rules:
`allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

4- To fix that, I am working on loading images to the memory using **getData()**

```dart
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
      app: Firestore.instance.app,
      storageBucket: 'gs://...'
);

  Uint8List imageBytes;
  String errorMsg;

SOME_CONSTRUCTOR() {
  storage
    .ref()
    .child(imageTitle)
    .getData(10000000)
    .then(..)..
}
```

then Load the image from memory:

```dart
Image.memory(imageBytes, fit: BoxFit.cover,)
```

this works fine but, I am looking for the **best practice** for this, and here's my questions:

A- Is this (fetch image) code should be **part of the load-from-db(the 'stream' of streamBuilder)** or later inside **creating-Cards from fetched data from db** (the 'builder' of the streamBuilder)?

B- Is there any possibility to load image while loading from db, assume every record in db has an image(1-to-1), so it will be like this:

```
fetch row-> download its image 

fetch row-> download its image 

THEN NEXT ROWs...
```

?

C- Or it's better to load Items then build Cards, then load images after that while the Cards are visible for the users?

D- Any other advices that may help me dealing with this?

Comment: salaam mate, you find a solution ?